# Modern approach to threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I would like to ask about approach to threads in C# today. I know that there are quite new words like `async` and `await` which can help with working with threads. What about something like this:

```
Task firstTask = new Task(() =>
{
    //some action
});
firstTask.Start();
```

How should I work with `Task`? Do I need to define `async` method and inside of it use methods like above? Can I write `await` instead of `firstTask.wait()` inside?

I need to merge two collections using two threads now. Is it good way to do something that I mentioned above?

Comment: For dealing with collections, you should take a look at PLINQ =)

Comment: `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => yourFuncHere());` in async function

Comment: merge two collections using two threads?! Surly you need only one thread to do that...

Comment: I didn't say that I agree with this idea. I just said I need to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first `Task` is not completely equal to threads

`Task` is some kind of work item, that can be done asynchronously and have a ability to wait or cancel. It is important to understand, that `TaskScheduler` decides whether to create new thread for the next task, to wait until some thread become free from the pool or to run in the current thread

On the opposite side, you can use `Thread` or `ThreadPool` manually if you want to make sure that physical thread will be created or to be taken from pool

`async/await` is nothing more than a syntax sugar around `Tasks`

So

`Thread/Threadpool` are underlying classes for dealing with physical threads

`Task`s are more high level library, that treat async opperation as separate part of work, that need to be done separately

`async/await` is syntax sugar, that make some common tasks easier

Answer (score 2):

In short `Task` is an abstraction around asynchronously executed work. Using Tasks is a recommended approach nowadays.

Sometimes `Task` has a corresponding background `Thread` allocated on `ThreadPool` (e.g. when you run some calculation using `Task.Run(() => {Calculate});`, sometimes it uses system features to do I/O operartions asynchronously **without** consuming an additional thread on `ThreadPool` (e.g. when you read a file with `FileStream.ReadAsync` [Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158566%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) )

There's too much asked in your question, I suggest that you go to documentation first:

- [Parallel Programming in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx)
- [Threading (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx)
- [Asynchronous Programming Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better if you start with a little literature :)

[The Basics of Task Parallelism via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C)

[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

[Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to enumerating collections. They have to be invariant, meaning that you can't modify them when a thread is in a `foreach`, or that thread (the one enumerating, not the one modifying the collection) will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. This is very difficult to debug.

You'll have to be careful and `lock()` on occasion like this:

```
lock (coll)
{
    foreach (var item in coll)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also lock the modifying side:

```
lock (coll)
{
    coll.Add(item);
}
```